# How to change default format of Date in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I'm having problem with the date format of rails. It seems to me that the default Date Format is `dd/mm/yyyy`. How am I gonna change it to something like `mm/dd/yyyy`?

I read somewhere that ActiveSupport gem can handle this but I don't how it works.

Comment: You want to do that while displaying the date right?

Comment: Yes. I want to format it somewhere in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put following line in your enviroment.rb

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and try

```
 Time.now.to_date.to_s
```

On you rails console

Comment: I placed this one in my environment. Will it function in rails console? I tried this in my rails console: "11/29/2010".to_date but it says "invalid date".

Comment: Tested on my home desktop. Please try now/

Answer (score 2):

You can add the file into the `config/initializers` folder having name i.e. (date_time_formats.rb). Simply add following line to the file.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

As per requirement you can change date format.