# How do I change the format ActiveRecord expects when parsing dates from a text field in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

### The problem

1. I have a Ruby on Rails model with a Date attribute.
2. In the form for this model, I am using a single text field with a JQuery datepicker to represent this attribute (not a drop down for each of year, month, and day, as is the Rails custom).
3. The datepicker inserts dates with a `mm/dd/yyyy` format.
4. Rails is expecting dates with a `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

### Examples

- If a user selects *March 12th, 2012*, the datepicker puts `03/12/2012`, which is interpreted by Rails as *December 3rd, 2012*.
- If a user selects *March 20th, 2012*, the datepicker puts `03/20/2012`, which is interpreted by Rails as the 3rd day of the **20th month** of 2012. Since this date doesn't exist, Rails casts this to a `nil` value (I think).

### Question

How do I change the date format Rails uses when parsing this date text field?

Notes:

1) I do not want to change the format of the date the datepicker inserts into the text field,

2) I am not asking about displaying my date attribute in a view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I initially thought this could be solved through the Rails internationalization features, but it turns out I was wrong.

Ever since Ruby 1.9, the standard format for date parsing is `dd/mm/yyyy`, so as to better accomodate international users. More details can be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373165/1512956).

That standard is maintained in Rails, as `Date.parse` is now used to process data from form inputs. Using a `before_validation` callback won't work because the field is going to be received as `nil` by the callback method.

Right now there are two gems dealing with this specific issue, namely that date parsing in Rails does not follow the locale settings from `I18n.locale`. Both seem to work well.

1. [**delocalize**](https://github.com/clemens/delocalize), by clemens - Seems to have been applied successfully in a decent number or projects and has the highest number of stars at the moment.
2. [**i18n_alchemy**](https://github.com/carlosantoniodasilva/i18n_alchemy) by carlosantoniodasilva - This one has been released more recently. The author is a Rails core team member, and a very active one at that. Definitely deserves a look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I can tell, by using I18n, I can only change the way dates are _displayed_, not the way they are parsed by ActiveRecord. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually in your case the Datepicker is responsible for filling in the date field, but Rails is going to parse that content according to the i18n settings. I have a project where I had to solve exactly that same problem.

Comment: More specifically, you want Rails to expect dates in a mm/dd/yyyy format. By using the correct locale setting and YAML file, you can do exactly that.

Comment: Quick tip: If you open a console and type `I18n.locale` you can see the current setting used by the app.

Comment: Hmmm, I must not be changing the right thing in the `en.yml` file. I changed `en -> date -> formats -> default` to be `! '%m/%d/%Y'`. That changed the way dates were outputted, so I know localization is working, but it did not change the way dates were parsed.

Comment: You mentioned Rails was expecting dates in dd/mm/yyyy format before. Which locale were you using? Are you sure Rails is using the right one now?

Comment: Try to play around with the field in console, setting new dates using `update_attributes` and then reading the same field to check if the date has been properly set.

Comment: I haven't changed the default locale. Doing `I18n.locale` from the Rails console returns `:en`. Changing the date format to `! %m/%d/%Y` changes to output of `l Date.today` in my views from `2013-03-25` to `03/25/2013`, so I know internationalization is working as expected. However, I still cannot save a date string of `03/25/2013` for March 25th, 2013. It is being cast to `nil`, as far as I can tell. Also, a date string of `03/12/2013` is parsed to `December 3rd, 2013` instead of `March 12th, 2013`.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for this, but I believe ActiveRecord is using `Date.parse` to do the parsing. In my Rails console `Date.parse` also expects dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I don't know if there's any way to change this though. I'm getting the feeling that the virtual attribute approach from @jameschen is the best way to accomplish what I want to do. I just wish I could find some definitive documentation.

Comment: Yes, AR is using `Date.parse` to do the parsing. The approach I'm suggesting is more consistent with i18n settings, so that's why I prefer it. There's also the solution proposed in this SO question, but I haven't tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256510/how-to-change-default-format-of-date-in-rails-3

The fact that one of the gems above was written by a Rails core member is a good sign that this is a good approach, in my opinion.

Comment: A good solution will not only use the locale from i18n.locale, but it will also apply to the whole application. If you need to create a virtual property and a callback for each field that needs to be formatted, you're not being very DRY: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: The `delocalize` gem worked for me. A note to others also trying `delocalize`: when following along with their README, use the YAML syntax in the Psych section for your input formats.

Comment: https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date was my solution. This is frankly embarrassing for Rails. I haven't been able to find a discussion on why i18n doesn't get applied to the Ruby layer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want to change the picker's format, I would suggest you use a hidden field for the actual model property.

For example, add a hidden field for the model's date property, assuming you use a form builder as usual:

`f.hidden_field :date`

Then for the picker text input, don't bind it to the model's date property. Let's say the hidden field has ID 'modelname_date' and the picker text input has ID 'date_picker', use the following to make it work:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#date_picker").datepicker({altField: '#nodelname_date', altFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
});
```

In this way the date picker shows the date as 'mm/dd/yyyy' but Rails will see the date as 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

**Update:**

If you want to work this out on the Rails side, here's another solution I'd suggest:

- Add a virtual property to your model: `attr_accessor :bad_format_date`
- Add a before_validation callback in which you parse the input date and assign it to the real field:

```ruby
before_validation do
  self.date = Date.strptime(bad_format_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

Then for the form on the view use `bad_format_date` but initialize it with the `date` field value (if it's an edit form).

Comment: This seems like a roundabout way to get where I'm trying to go. I would really like to do this on the Rails side. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to accomplish this without a virtual attribute on the model? I ask because it seems like a heavy weight solution to simply changing the date format being parsed. In doing some playing around in my Rails console, I believe that ActiveRecord is using `Date.parse` to do the date parsing, but can't find documentation to confirm my hunch. Was wondering if you knew? I'm probably going to award the bounty to your answer, but I would really like to provide future visitors with the Why this is the best way to accomplish this, not just the How.

Answer (score 0):

The [timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/timeliness) gem makes ruby date/time parsing much more customizeable and integrates well with Rails.

Since you're working with Rails, be sure to check out the [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) project as well by the same guy. It includes all of timeliness plus sophisticated date/time validation methods for ActiveModel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try do something like this.

```
$(function(){
 $('#date_picker').datepicker( {
      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      defaultDate: date,
      gotoCurrent: true

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I specifically mentioned that I am _not_ looking to change the format that the datepicker inserts into the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I just add the following monkey patch to config/time_formats.rb

```
class Date
  class << self
    alias :euro_parse :_parse
    def _parse(str,comp=false)
      str = str.to_s.strip
      if str == ''
        {}
      elsif str =~ /^(\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{2,4})/
        year,month,day = $3.to_i,$1,$2
        date,*rest = str.split(' ')
        year += (year < 35 ? 2000 : 1900) if year < 100
        euro_parse("#{year}-#{month}-#{day} #{rest.join(' ')}",comp)
      else
        euro_parse(str,comp)
      end  
    end
  end
end
```