# Rails 4 parse a date in a different language

Tags: internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I have a `text_field :birthday_line` in my user form, that I need to parse into the user's `birthday` attribute. 
So I'm doing something like this in my `User` class.

```
attr_accessor :birthday_line
before_save :set_birthday

def set_birthday
  self.birthday = Date.strptime(birthday_line, I18n.translate("date.formats.default")
end
```

But the problem is that for some reason it gives me an error saying `Invalid date` when I try to pass in a string `27 января 1987 г.` wich should be parsed to `1987-01-27`.
The format and month names in my `config/locales/ru.yml`

```
ru:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d %B %Y г."
    month_names: [~, января, февраля, марта, апреля, мая, июня, июля, августа, сентября, октября, ноября, декабря]
```

seem to be correct.

`Date.parse` also doesn't help, it just parses the day number (27) and puts the month and year to todays date (so it'll be September 27 2013 instead of January 27 1987).

Comment: I18n.l(user.birthday) works fine though. So the i18n locale should be correct.

Comment: Isn't that the same as this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531786/how-do-i-change-the-format-activerecord-expects-when-parsing-dates-from-a-text-f/15607550

Comment: depa: not realy. I think the biggest part of my problem is parsing the month names, and the smallest is about the format itself. So the givven solutions don't really fit. I have seen the `delocalize` gem, but it's still out of Rails 4 support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and what I can suggest:

```
string_with_cyrillic_date = '27 Января 1987'
```

1)create array of arrays like this

```
months = [["января", "Jan"], ["февраля", "Feb"], ["марта", "Mar"], ["апреля", "Apr"], ["мая", "May"], ["июня", "Jun"], ["июля", "Jul"], ["августа", "Aug"], ["сентября", "Sep"], ["октября", "Oct"], ["ноября", "Nov"], ["декабря", "Dec"]]
```

2) Now you can iterate this and find your cyrillic month:

```
months.each do |cyrillic_month, latin_month|
  if string_with_cyrillic_date.match cyrillic_month      
    DateTime.parse string_with_cyrillic_date.gsub!(/#{cyrillic_month}/, latin_month) 
  end
end
```

And now you will receive the date that you expect

```
27 Jan 1987
```